Can we check the optimality gap between the solution found within a specified time limit and the actual optimal solution in CPLEX OPL?
In CPLEX OPL code, I have specified a time limit of 1800 seconds for obtaining a solution. How can I determine the optimality gap between the solution I'm obtaining and the true global optimal solution ? Is there any way to specify both the optimality gap and time limit in the cplex opl code ?

In postprocessing you can compute the gap
https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoogap.mod
execute
 {
   cplex.intsollim=2;
 }

int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
 
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
} 

execute
{
  writeln("nbbus40 = ",nbBus40);
  writeln("nbbus30 = ",nbBus30);
  writeln("obj =",cplex.getObjValue());
  writeln("best obj =",cplex.getBestObjValue());
  writeln("gap = ",(Math.abs(
  cplex.getBestObjValue()-cplex.getObjValue()))/(Math.abs(1e-10+cplex.getObjValue())));
  writeln("gap = ",cplex.getMIPRelativeGap());
}

/*

// solution (solution limit exceeded) with objective 3900
nbbus40 = 7
nbbus30 = 1
obj =3900
best obj =3750
gap = 0.038461538
gap = 0.038461538

*/

You can specify both the optimality gap and time limit in the cplex opl code :
See https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoosetting1.mod for time limit
execute
{
  cplex.tilim=20;
}


int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
     
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
     
minimize
     costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
     
subject to
{
   40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
}

execute
{
    writeln("time limit = ",cplex.tilim);
}

for the gap
execute
{
  cplex.epgap=0.01;
}


